# FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable in GCP Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, credentials, google-cloud-run

[This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) explains:

> Note: The FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is included automatically in Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that were deployed via the Firebase CLI.

Can we get access to the same FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable in Cloud Run environment? If yes, how?
If no, please give instructions on setting firebase-admin `initializeApp` and firebase `initializeApp` for authentication on Cloud Run.

Should we save the serviceAccount and firebase-config in our project and import them? If so, what are the best practices for doing that? When working on an open-source project, we should put these files in .gitignore. Then how should we push them to the Cloud Run environment using `gcloud` CLI?

Comment: You've got too many questions here - please limit yourself to a single question per post.  As far as I know, if you want something equivalent to FIREBASE_CONFIG, you'll have to establish that yourself using whatever method you prefer, built into the docker image that you deploy.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your quick response. I always find your posts really helpful. So, would you please give me a link or instructions for setting firebase-admin initializeApp and firebase initializeApp for authentication on Cloud Run? I Googled it a lot but cannot find anything. Are there any instructions to migrate a web app on Cloud Functions to Cloud RUN? I understand that I can set up everything in the environment in my Docker file, but I'm looking for best practices for the Firebase credentials setup.

Comment: @DougStevenson Following your advice on limiting myself to a single question per page, I created a separate thread asking my main question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033551/how-can-i-obtain-gcp-service-account-credentials-on-google-cloud-run