# How Can I Obtain GCP service account credentials on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin, google-cloud-run, google-iam

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) explains both:

1. [Obtaining and providing service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) for developing local, deploying on-premises, or deploying to another public cloud.
2. [Obtaining credentials on Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine flexible environment, and Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_compute_engine_kubernetes_engine_app_engine_flexible_environment_and_cloud_functions)

But there is no mention of obtaining credentials on Cloud Run. I'd appreciate it if you give instructions for obtaining credentials and setting firebase-admin `initializeApp` and firebase `initializeApp` for authentication on Cloud Run.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation suggests that you can use the default service account just like other Google Cloud products as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity).  The Firebase Admin SDK should use that account when initialized with no parameters.

There are also steps described if you want to [use a non-default service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#deploying_a_new_service_with_a_non-default_identity), which you can simply configure in the console or provide with gcloud.

If you must provide a file that's readable at runtime, you will have to deploy an image with that file added to the image.  There is no short set of steps to add that file - you will have to make your docker build include it in a readable location, and your code will know where to look for it in order to load it.

Comment: When I initial Firebase Admin SDK with no parameters, it returns the following error message:
```
{ [Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.]
  code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
  message: 'Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.' }
```

Comment: The admin sdk does not need credentials when initializing on a server - if that server runs on GCP -. The firebase sdk (you call initializeApp on it), does need the API key and firebase config

Comment: @WietseVenema Which documentation page did you find this information on? Also, I'd appreciate it if you answer my original question: please give instructions for obtaining credentials and setting firebase-admin initializeApp and firebase initializeApp for authentication on Cloud Run. If I have to pass the API key and firebase config, what is the best practice in passing it to my Cloud Run Node.js App?

Comment: @WietseVenema https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters 
explains: "Note: The FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is included automatically in Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that were deployed via the Firebase CLI." Then why should I get that error?

Comment: Your question asks about Cloud Run, which is a completely different product than Cloud Functions.  They don't work the same way, and Firebase doesn't offer a deployer for Cloud Run that sets things up like it does special for Cloud Functions.